# How to switch to monitor mode using NDIS?

Tags: c++, monitor, wdk, ndis, netmon

I'm writing a program (C++) which will detect devices around me using Wi-fi on Windows OS.
In order to do that I'm using Netmon API and I need to switch the wireless network adapter to monitor mode. 

I read that Netmon doesn't have an API for that and therefore I need to do it using WDK and NDIS.

Does anyone know how to switch to monitor mode?
I would appreciate a code sample.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In usermode, switch the wireless interface into monitor mode with

```
WlanSetInterface(
    . . . ,
    wlan_intf_opcode_current_operation_mode,
    DOT11_OPERATION_MODE_NETWORK_MONITOR);
```